# My navigation bar is gone!

Tags: magento2, frontend, navigation

My navigation bar is gone there must be a navigation bar like in the bottom picture. Help! TT
[image: My navigation bar is gone!]

[image: There must be a navigation bar like this!]

Comment: check console log and try after cache flush and clear in private browser.
have you used empty layout for that category?

Comment: I used 1 column for my layout

Comment: share that layout. Also check is there any code to remove menu in 1 column layout?

Comment: What do you mean by share?

Comment: I mean add that layiut contet in your question.

Comment: My bad the layout was really empty. I change it and clear the cache and it's back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ahh ok, welcome!

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: The layout was empty!

Comment: ok, so you did not added anything in that layout, right?

Comment: I forgot that it was empty so i change it to 1 column!

Comment: I have added answer please accept it so it will help to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used as empty layout, please Correct it as 1 column or another one.